# Newly created Asana Tags (created in web interface) are not returned from the API

Tags: tags, asana

I can pull tags that were created a week or more ago from the API using the /tags or /workspaces/{id}/tags endpoints.  However anything that I create today does not appear in the responses from the API.

The tags I created ARE associated with tasks.  I created them in the web interface, not the API, so there is no way to grab the ID from a POST request like others on here have done.

This seems like a pretty huge feature-breaking bug.  Any thoughts/workarounds?

*Edit 1*

I discovered that if I comment on a task that has a newly created tag, the tag suddenly will appear.  Maybe you guys are missing a call to an update hook when only the tags have been updated?

Comment: From the description, it sounds like *possibly* the API user doesn't have access to the tasks that the tag is associated with? It's hard to know without further details. I suspect access control is involved in some way - we are a little paranoid, I suppose, and when there are access control bugs (or just weird edge cases) it tends to result in things not being visible when they should be (or seem like they should be).

Is the API acting on behalf of the same account that created the tag? That associated the tag with the tasks? Can the API user see the tasks?

Comment: The API __is__ acting on the behalf of the user that created the original tasks.  The Workspace, Tasks, Tags, and Comments were all created by the same user.  And the API token was requested on behalf of that same user.  The API token has full permissions as well.

Comment: Okay, hmm. Thanks for clarifying, I'm trying to figure out exactly what makes the tag "show up" - leaving a comment doesn't seem to do the trick for me, but following the tag does. I'm going to file this as a bug internally, thanks for the report!

Comment: no problem, i will keep posting if i figure anything else funny about it. won't be back on this problem for a couple of days